# passing image files in post request parameter of JavaScript and then getting that image info in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending array of images and some text from javascript ajax function to php file and i can read text parameters but i cannot read image file parameters in php code how can i do that?
**Javascript code**
'''

```
formdata.append("file",img[i]);

xhttp.send("itemname="+itemname+"&category="+category+"&color="+color+"&price="+price
    +"&image="+formdata+"&brandname="+brandname+"&attributes="+attributes+"&smalldescp="+smalldesp
    +"&longdescp="+largedescp+"&warentyyear="+warentyyr+"&warentydescp="+warentypolicydescp+"&length="+pkglen
    +"&width="+pkgweight+"&height="+pkgheg);'''
```

**Php Code**
'''

```
 $itemname = $_POST["itemname"];
   $category = $_POST["category"];
   $color = $_POST["color"];
   $price = $_POST["price"];
   $image =$_POST["image"];
   $brandname = $_POST["brandname"];
   $attributes = $_POST["attributes"];
   $smalldescp = $_POST["smalldescp"];
   $longdescp = $_POST["longdescp"];
   $warentyyear = $_POST["warentyyear"];
   $warentydescp = $_POST["warentydescp"];
   $length = $_POST["length"];
   $width = $_POST["width"];
   $height = $_POST["height"];
     
     echo json_encode($image->$_FILES['file']['name'][0]);
```

'''

Comment: There are many many guides/tutorials/questions/answers about sending files using ajax both here on SO and on the internet in general. I suggest you do some proper research and read through some of them.

Comment: Data is passing fine the issue is i cannot read image file in php this is how i am trying to read a file name **echo json_encode($image->$_FILES['file']['name'][0]);** i researched a lot but i cannot find out

Comment: I'm guessing that all those params comes from one form (that also has the file input?) Then just do `$data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#theFormId')); xhttp.send($data);`. If you don't just have one form, then you can add all params to the FormData object. I would also recommend using the easier and more modern `fetch()`-api over `XMLHttpRequest` (which I'm guessing you're using)

Comment: the way i am sending is any way to send like that from javascript or not? in xhttp.send(). Yes they are coming from form